# VBA movefile from a list in Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to move files to another folder from an Excel file (listfiles.xlsx) which contains paths of files in column A. The code below didn't work for me, can you help me please?

```
Sub movefile1()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim i As Long
Dim worksh As Worksheet
Dim workboo As Workbook

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Destination = "C:\Users\Desktop\Folder"

Set workboo = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\list_files.xlsx")
Set worksh = Worksheets("Listing")

numRows = worksh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
workboo.Windows(1).Visible = False

        For i = 2 To numRows
        Filepath = worksh.Range("A" & i).Value
        fso.CopyFile Filepath, Destination
    Next

    End Sub
```

I changed the code but the `fso.CopyFile Filepath, Destination` does not work. They say permission refused

Comment: `Dim excelfile as String`?? This cannot work in combination with the line `Set excelfile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\output file\listfiles.xlsx")`. Rather use `Dim excelfile As Workbook`. Also, if you are using libraries then please include them in your description or the code: `' Used reference "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"`. Finally, you might want to update your `With` statement to include the (just opened) Excel file: `With excelfile.Worksheets("Sheet1")`.

Comment: @Ralph thank you i changed that but now i have a problem in last line . a permission problem

Comment: Then this is no longer a VBA programming problem but rather a permission problem you will have to solve with your local system administrator. There is nothing we can do here to change your permissions.

Comment: hmm . but i m in administrator session .

Comment: once again, this site is all about programming problems and (in your above example) about VBA programming problems in particular. If you have a problem with your permissions then you might want to check out another site and ask your question there. Yet, if you do, you might want to include some background information. Otherwise, we will have to guess: what is the file-system you are trying to access (Linux / Windows), what are the current permissions in place, which way are you using to authenticate yourself, is it a local or a remove file-system (possibly including the path), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Place the line `numRows = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` before the loop, otherwise the loop won't be executed at all

Comment: yes in the line  numRows = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 and then like the excel file do not open to use their information to move the files

Comment: numRows = sheet1.Range("A" & sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row they say error 424

Comment: @JeanLo `sheet1.Range("...` is a code name for a sheet. Code names can be only used for the Excel file in which the code resides (the file which is hosting the macro). Yet, I believe that you want to refer to the sheet1 on the newly opened Excel file. In that case you will have to do as written in my comment above (you cannot use the worksheet code name in this case).

Comment: @Ralph i changed the code . now it s fso.CopyFile Filepath, Destination do not work . they say permission refused :s

Comment: If you don't have permission to write to a certain directory or to overwrite a file (that might exist) then that is a permission problem and not a programming problem.